# I have been trying to import databse log into logstash, but im getting error of SSL

Tags: java, logstash, elk

I am using MS SQL EXPRESS as a Database and I want to fetch the database from that MS SQL to my logstash, but I am getting error of SSL server connection.

Code:

```
    input {
    jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars/sqljdbc42.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://x.x.x.x:1433;encrypt=false;databaseName=xxxxxx;"
    jdbc_user => "xx"
    jdbc_password => "xxxxxx"
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT [ID],
          [userName]
         ,[orgName]
         ,[serial]
         ,[actDate]
         ,[action]
         ,[result]
         ,[sourceIP]
         ,[agentID]
         ,[message]
         ,[siteHost]
         ,[orgID]
         ,[usedName]
         ,[credentialType]
    FROM [BlackShield1].[dbo].[AuthenticationActivity]"
   use_column_value => true
   tracking_column => "userName"
  }
 }
  output {
  elasticsearch {
  hosts => "localhost:9200"
  index => "authen_use"
  document_id => "%{productid}" # use lower case.
  }
}
```

Im getting error like:
Unable to connect to database. Tried 1 times {:error_message=>"Java::ComMicrosoftSqlserverJdbc::SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol version is not enabled or not supported by the client.". ClientConnectionId:b2eb3206-46a7-4470-97d5-24fce2a11cee"}

Please find my jdk version:

- openjdk version "1.8.0_262"
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_262-b10)
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.262-b10, mixed mode

Comment: Have you tried messing with `encrypt=false`?

Comment: yes i did , but it didnt helped me

Comment: From this machine, have you been able to create any other jdbc connection outside logstash?

Comment: no, this is my first time connection

Comment: Alright, well, since it seems like a client issue, and not logstash, I'd suggest debugging using other tools. Or maybe another JDBC driver

Comment: i have tried two jdbc driver sqljdbc42.jar and sqljdbc41.jar, but none of them worked, you mentioned tool for debugging, could you provide me some specific tool names.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221169/discussion-between-prashant-dhimal-and-onecricketeer).